# How to convert unsigned long to string

Tags: c

In the C language, how do I convert **unsigned long**  value to a string (**char ***) and keep my source code portable or just recompile it to work on other platform (without rewriting code?

For example, if I have `sprintf(buffer, format, value)`, how do I determine the size of buffer with platform-independent manner?

Comment: with sprintf,  how to determine the size of buffer with platform-independent manner

Comment: @Walidix the answer is probably limits.h : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limits.h

Comment: This is actually a big weakness of sprintf, partially fixed in C++ by using streams rather than buffers. The usual "answer" is to allocate a very generous buffer unlikely to overflow, let sprintf output to that, and then use `strlen` to determine the actual string length produced, `calloc` a buffer of (that size + 1) and copy the string to that.

Comment: @Walidix: You need to compute `log10(ULONG_MAX)`...

Comment: A foolproof answer is `snprintf` if you have it. See my answer for a little more detail.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
const int n = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%lu", ulong_value);
assert(n > 0);
char buf[n+1];
int c = snprintf(buf, n+1, "%lu", ulong_value);
assert(buf[n] == '\0');
assert(c == n);
```

Comment: Note the VLA (`char buf[n+1];`) requires C99.

Comment: 2014 and I'm still stuck using Visual Studio in work for Windows development which doesn't allow it :(

Comment: Excellent answer, and one to throw in the face of people who think it can't be done without difficulty unless you use C++.  I'm looking at you, Carl Smotricz!!

Answer (score 7):

The standard approach is to use `sprintf(buffer, "%lu", value);` to write a string rep of `value` to `buffer`. However, overflow is a potential problem, as `sprintf` will happily (and unknowingly) write over the end of your buffer.

This is actually a big weakness of sprintf, partially fixed in C++ by using streams rather than buffers. The usual "answer" is to allocate a very generous buffer unlikely to overflow, let sprintf output to that, and then use strlen to determine the actual string length produced, calloc a buffer of (that size + 1) and copy the string to that.

[This site](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/s-buffer-defend.html) discusses this and related problems at some length.

Some libraries offer `snprintf` as an alternative which lets you specify a maximum buffer size.

Comment: Yes, i would use `snprintf`. It's Standard, and it provides support for completely solving this.

Comment: Contradicting your gravatar, +1 for sanity.

Comment: Printing a number is a case where you don't need `snprintf`; you can easily bound the size of buffer required. (Printing with `%s` OTOH, that requires caution.)

Comment: Many programmers will feel better specifying a very explicit upper bound with `snprintf` than using considerations about the sizes of numbers to mathematically establish such a bound or -worse, IMO- fiddling with logarithms to pre-calculate that size.

Answer (score 5):

you can write a function which converts from unsigned long to str, similar to ltostr library function.

```
char *ultostr(unsigned long value, char *ptr, int base)
{
  unsigned long t = 0, res = 0;
  unsigned long tmp = value;
  int count = 0;

  if (NULL == ptr)
  {
    return NULL;
  }

  if (tmp == 0)
  {
    count++;
  }

  while(tmp > 0)
  {
    tmp = tmp/base;
    count++;
  }

  ptr += count;

  *ptr = '\0';

  do
  {
    res = value - base * (t = value / base);
    if (res < 10)
    {
      * -- ptr = '0' + res;
    }
    else if ((res >= 10) && (res < 16))
    {
        * --ptr = 'A' - 10 + res;
    }
  } while ((value = t) != 0);

  return(ptr);
}
```

you can refer to my blog [here](http://www.refcode.net/2013/02/unsigned-long-to-string-ultostr.html) which explains implementation and usage with example.

Answer (score 3):

```
char buffer [50];

unsigned long a = 5;

int n=sprintf (buffer, "%lu", a);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `sprintf`:

```
unsigned long x=1000000;
char buffer[21];
sprintf(buffer,"%lu", x);
```

Edit:

Notice that you have to allocate a buffer in advance, and have no idea how long the numbers will actually be when you do so. I'm assuming 32bit `long`s, which can produce numbers as big as 10 digits.

See Carl Smotricz's answer for a better explanation of the issues involved.

Answer (score 1):

For a long value you need to add the length info 'l' and 'u' for unsigned decimal integer,

as a reference of available options see [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/)

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main ()
    {
      unsigned long lval = 123;
      char buffer [50];
      sprintf (buffer, "%lu" , lval );
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

> ... how do I determine the size of buffer with platform-independent manner?

One of the challenges of converting a `unsigned long` to a string is how to determine the string size that is needed.

- Dynamically

Repeatedly divide the value by 10 until 0 to find `size_needed`.

```
value_copy = value;
unsigned size_needed = 1; // For the null character.
if (value_copy < 0) size_needed++; // Only needed for signed types.
do {
  size_needed++; // Add 1 per digit.
  value_copy /= 10;
} while (value_copy != 0);
```

- Worse case

Find the string length of `ULONG_MAX`.
Start with the nifty [`IMAX_BITS(m)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4589384/2410359) which returns the number of bits in a [Mersenne Number](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MersenneNumber.html) like `ULONG_MAX`. (This give us the max bit width even if the type has padding.) Then scale by log<sub>10</sub>2 (0.301...) to find the number of decimal digits and add 2 for rounding and the null character.

```
#define IMAX_BITS(m) ((m)/((m)%255+1) / 255%255*8 + 7-86/((m)%255+12))
#define LOG2_10_N  28
#define LOG2_10_D  93
#define UNSIGNED_LONG_STRING_SIZE (IMAX_BITS(ULONG_MAX)*LOG2_10_N/LOG2_10_D + 2)
// Slightly different for signed types, one more for the sign:
#define SIGNED_LONG_STRING_SIZE   (IMAX_BITS( LONG_MAX)*LOG2_10_N/LOG2_10_D + 3)
```

---

Armed with the string size, there are many possible next steps.  I like using C99's (and later) *compound literal* to form the needed space.  The space is valid until the end of the block.

```
char *unsigned_long_to_string(char *dest, unsigned long x) {
  sprintf(dest, "%lu", x);
  return dest;
}

// Compound literal                                        v-----------------------------------v
#define UNSIGNED_LONG_TO_STRING(u) unsigned_long_to_string((char [UNSIGNED_LONG_STRING_SIZE]){0}, (u))

int main(void) {
  puts(UNSIGNED_LONG_TO_STRING(42));
  puts(UNSIGNED_LONG_TO_STRING(ULONG_MAX));
}
```

Output

```
42
18446744073709551615  // This varies
```