# Setting a size_t variable to -1

Tags: c

If I set a `size_t` variable to -1, like in:

```
size_t s = -1;
```

Is it guaranteed it will contain the maximal value that can be hold by `s`?

For example, if `sizeof(size_t)` is 4 bytes, can I assume that `s` would be `0xFFFFFFFF`?

*As a complementary info: I need this for implementing a set, in which I intend to use **-1** as 'item doesn't exist'. And at the same time I don't want to sacrifice the **0**, nor using an `int`.*

Comment: No warning from `gcc -Wall -Wextra`.

Comment: @MikeMB I think `~0` is not guaranteed (well, at least not explicitly) to give the maximal value by the standard, while `-1` is.

Comment: @MikeMB I was thinking about padding bits. But apparently [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475540/c-question-padding-bits-in-unsigned-integers-and-bitwise-operations-c89) is telling that the bitwise operations should not affect these. So yeah, as I said it is probably correct but not as obvious from the standard.

Comment: @MikeMB `~0` will not work on rare non-2's complement platforms to give maximum `size_t`.  `~0u` will fail when `SIZE_MAX > UINT_MAX`.  Hard to beat `size_t s = SIZE_MAX;`

Comment: ["unsigned integers are guaranteed to be represent as two's complement."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45379143/setting-a-size-t-variable-to-1/45381164#comment77721269_45379143) --> two's complement is for signed integers.  Unsigned integers do  not use  two's complement.

Comment: @WeatherVane: It did for me with VS2017. Which version are you using? And what warning level?

Comment: @chux: You are right, that doesn't make sense. I have to check back what I did exactly. I removed the comments.

Comment: @MikeMB MSVC 2015 with default warning level from console not IDE. If yours did give you a warning, you must be right, but it read like you were guessing, or read it on the internet ;)

Comment: @WeatherVane: I did check here: https://godbolt.org/g/nFH3iw (I'm always compiling with /W4 on MSVC). What I did guess (poorly) was the syntax of my solution. As was written by chux and in the answers: The sane thing to do is using `SIZE_MAX`.

Comment: @MikeMB I wonder if there is a difference here between my C and your C++.

Comment: Can you not pass in the value to be modified as a reference or pointer, and have the function just return an error code? Example: `int some_function(size_t* val) { *val = 42; return -1; }` ..?

Comment: @txtechhelp I don't want to modify them, just storing them, and retrieve them later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is guaranteed to become the maximum, since `size_t` is always an unsigned integer type, and unsigned integer types are guaranteed to wrap / use modulo arithmetic. As [C11 6.3.1.3p2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3p2) says of converting integers (`-1` is a constant of type `int`) to unsigned integer types.

> [...] if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type.

---

However, `sizeof(size_t) == 4` doesn't mean that it has 32 bits, because `sizeof` tells the size in bytes - i.e. `char`s - and a `char` has `CHAR_BIT` bits. And even if `sizeof(size_t) * CHAR_BIT == 32`,  `size_t` can still have less than 32 value bits (the rest will be padding bits).

---

P.S. I'd recommend that you use [`SIZE_MAX`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.20.3) from [`<stdint.h>`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.20) instead.

Comment: I would reinforce it with [this](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3p2)

Comment: Also `size_t` could have padding bits. In any case, `-1` converted to `size_t` is the max possible value `size_t` can hold, but it might not be related to `sizeof(size_t)`.

Comment: Indeed, I assumed a byte = an octet

Comment: @R.. I've addressed that too;

Comment: @EugeneSh. thanks, I was trying to be the FGITW here ;)

Answer (score 1):

To [@Antti Haapala](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45379175/2410359) fine answer, I added this to address OP's higher goal.

> As a complementary info: I need this for implementing a set, in which I intend to use -1 as 'item doesn't exist'. And at the same time I don't want to sacrifice the 0, nor using an `int`.

Instead of a naked magic number like `-1`, define a value.  Rather than -1, use `SIZE_MAX`.  It is the right value *and* the matching promoted type.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#define ITEM_NO_EXIST (SIZE_MAX)

...
// size_t s = -1;
size_t s = ITEM_NO_EXIST;
...
if (s == ITEM_NO_EXIST) puts("Item does not exist");
```

Comment: Unfortunatly I'm using ANSI C (C89), and  `SIZE_MAX` doesn't exist. But I still intend to use a constant instead of the raw number -1.

Comment: @BiteBytes Lacking `SIZE_MAX`, recommend `#define ITEM_NO_EXIST ((size_t) -1)`.

Comment: I can use `SIZE_MAX = 2 << (sizeof(size_t)*CHAR_BIT) -1) -1`, and define CHAR_BIT, depending on the architecture, (usually 8).

Comment: @BiteBytes `(2 << (sizeof(size_t)*CHAR_BIT) -1) -1)` fails when `SIZE_MAX > INT_MAX` - which is common.  `((size_t) -1)` is much better.

Comment: why does it fail?

Comment: @BiteBytes Let's be fair, tell me why it works.  (Hint watch type widths and signness)

Comment: I guessed it might work if `SIZE_MAX <= LONG_MAX`. Even if `SIZE_MAX > INT_MAX`, doesn't a processor promote the whole thing to `long` if `int` ain't enough to hold the result?

Comment: @BiteBytes No, and even `long` could be insufficient for a `size_t` as `unsigned long`