# Determine `sizeof float` without compilation

Tags: c, gcc, sizeof

I'd like to know the size of a `float` in GCC, without having to run the compiler. I know one option is to write a small function and have the compiler print out an assembly listing.

There is `limits.h`, which contains the minimums and maximums, but is there something similar that tells the size of the different implicit types?

I'm using GCC on Windows 7 x64; the target platform is ARM7 32 bit mode. Language is C.

Comment: The answer is 42...

Comment: FWIW it looks like [Autoconf resorts to compilation](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/autoconf/Specific-Compiler-Characteristics.html).

Comment: @Tomalak Gert'kal:  Yes, this is about GCC and how one can find the sizes of primitive types for a given platform.

Comment: OK, so really nothing about ARM. Nor C++...

Comment: what's wrong with `sizeof(float)`?

Comment: @Chris Dodd I'm assuming the author doesn't want to have to compile a program (which you would have to do to calculate `sizeof(float)`)

Comment: @Chris Dodd: The `sizeof(float)` requires compilation and at a minimum printing out an assembly language listing.  Running a simple program on our embedded system is more difficult.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: nor is this question about the C language - it is purely about the particular instance of GCC in use.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can have GCC print out all of the default macros:

```
gcc -dM -E - </dev/null | grep FLT
```

Then you get lines like:

```
#define __FLT_MANT_DIG__ 24
#define __FLT_MAX_EXP__ 128
```

Now you can parse this as follows:

```
24 + lg(128) + 1 = 32
```

To find documentation:

1) `man gcc`:

```
   -E  Stop after the preprocessing stage; do not run the compiler proper.
       The output is in the form of preprocessed source code, which is
       sent to the standard output.

...

   -dCHARS
       CHARS is a sequence of one or more of the following characters, and
       must not be preceded by a space.  Other characters are interpreted
       by the compiler proper, or reserved for future versions of GCC, and
       so are silently ignored.  If you specify characters whose behavior
       conflicts, the result is undefined.

       M   Instead of the normal output, generate a list of #define
           directives for all the macros defined during the execution of
           the preprocessor, including predefined macros.  This gives you
           a way of finding out what is predefined in your version of the
           preprocessor.  Assuming you have no file foo.h, the command

                   touch foo.h; cpp -dM foo.h

           will show all the predefined macros.
```

2) the actual macros:

http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Floating-Point-Parameters.html

Comment: Any `man` page or command line help options?  I couldn't find anything on the web manual.

Comment: By the way, if you need a macro to compute the log base 2 of `__FLT_MAX_EXP__` at preprocessor-time, try adapting this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4589384/379897

Answer (score 8):

The answer is 4. Any reasonable C implementation conforms to IEEE 754, which defines `float` ("single precision") as a 32-bit binary floating point type with 1 sign bit, 23 mantissa bits, and 8 exponent bits. You will never encounter anything different from this in the real world.

This answer is even more definitive since you specified GCC. GCC does not support any targets where `float` is not 32-bit.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that you just want this to help you determine what the size of various types on your target system is without having to actually run a program on the target system, but you don't intend on this being some sort of tool integrated into a build system, I may have a hack for you...

The hack does require running the compiler to compile a program, but you don't have to run the compiled output anywhere.  In fact, this hack is designed to tell you what you want to know by generating compiler errors.

The little macro here will cause the compiler to spit out an error message that corresponds to the size of the type given.  It'll also spit out an error message about the 'end of the search' just in case you pass it a type that's larger than what it checks.  That's just a 'convenience' to remind you to go add a bunch more lines to the macro so it'll handle the type you're curious about.

Some of the main limitations are:

- it's horribly hacky
- it tells you the information in a god-awful way
- it'll only work with types that can be expressed as a single word (so a `typedef` is necessary for things like `long double` as shown in the example).

But if you're ever curious about the size of some type, and don't want to actually run a program on the target to `printf()` the information, this may help.

Here's the macro(s) along with some examples of it being used:

```
#if !defined( PASTE)
#define PASTE2( x, y) x##y
#define PASTE( x, y)  PASTE2( x, y)
#endif /* PASTE */

#define SAY_IF_SIZEOF( type, size)   static char PASTE( PASTE( PASTE( sizeof_, type), _is_), size) [(sizeof(type) == (size)) ? -1 : 1]
#define SAY_SIZEOF_END(type) static char PASTE( end_search_for_sizeof_, type)[-1]

#define SAY_SIZEOF(type) \
    SAY_IF_SIZEOF( type, 1); \
    SAY_IF_SIZEOF( type, 2); \
    SAY_IF_SIZEOF( type, 3); \
    SAY_IF_SIZEOF( type, 4); \
    SAY_IF_SIZEOF( type, 5); \
    SAY_IF_SIZEOF( type, 6); \
    SAY_IF_SIZEOF( type, 7); \
    SAY_IF_SIZEOF( type, 8); \
    SAY_IF_SIZEOF( type, 9); \
    SAY_IF_SIZEOF( type, 10); \
    SAY_IF_SIZEOF( type, 11); \
    SAY_IF_SIZEOF( type, 12); \
    SAY_IF_SIZEOF( type, 13); \
    SAY_IF_SIZEOF( type, 14); \
    SAY_IF_SIZEOF( type, 15); \
    SAY_IF_SIZEOF( type, 16); \
    SAY_SIZEOF_END(type)


//here's where you get to ask about the size of a type

SAY_SIZEOF(float);

typedef long double long_double;

SAY_SIZEOF(long_double);


struct foo {
    char x;
    short y;
    int* p;
};

struct bar {
    char x;
    int* p;
    short y;
};

typedef struct foo foo_t;
typedef struct bar bar_t;

SAY_SIZEOF(foo_t);
SAY_SIZEOF(bar_t);

int main(void)
{

    return 0;
}
```

And here's what compiling that program with GCC/MinGW 4.5.1 says:

```
C:\temp\test.c:34:1: error: size of array 'sizeof_float_is_4' is negative
C:\temp\test.c:34:1: error: size of array 'end_search_for_sizeof_float' is negative
C:\temp\test.c:38:1: error: size of array 'sizeof_long_double_is_12' is negative
C:\temp\test.c:38:1: error: size of array 'end_search_for_sizeof_long_double' is negative
C:\temp\test.c:56:1: error: size of array 'sizeof_foo_t_is_8' is negative
C:\temp\test.c:56:1: error: size of array 'end_search_for_sizeof_foo_t' is negative
C:\temp\test.c:57:1: error: size of array 'sizeof_bar_t_is_12' is negative
C:\temp\test.c:57:1: error: size of array 'end_search_for_sizeof_bar_t' is negative
```

So, you can easily see that:

- `float` is 4 bytes
- `long double` is 12 bytes
- `struct foo` is 8 bytes
- `struct bar` is 12 bytes (different than `struct foo` due to alignment/padding differences)

Hope this helps. Actually, there have been times when I would want this...  Generally, if I'm curious about the size of a struct on my embedded targets I poke around in the debugger for that info or I have to hack in a debug `printf()` somewhere.

I think this would actually be easier to use:

- wonder how big something is
- drop a `SAY_SIZEOF()` 'call' into the source file
- hit Shift-Ctrl-B (or whatever the hotkey is to compile/build), get the info, and
- delete the `SAY_SIZEOF()` 'call'

Comment: This is a GREAT hack! I've sometimes had to resort to "manual binary search" using a `static_assert(sizeof(x) > X)` -> compile, rinse and repeat. This is loads better! When it takes a while to load and run e.g. an embedded target, it's often nice to be able to know the `sizeof` something at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be gdb: Just run it without any program and execute `sizeof(float)`. The problem is that your target and host platform are not the same, so you would have to run them on your arm-gdb.