# What is the easiest way to find the sizeof a type without compiling and executing code?

Tags: c, bash, gcc, sizeof

I wrote a bash script to determine the size of `gcc`'s datatypes (e.g. `./sizeof int double` outputs the respective sizes of `int` and `double`) by wrapping each of its arguments in the following `P()` macro and then compiling and running the code.

```
#define P(x) printf("sizeof(" #x ") = %u\n", (unsigned int)sizeof(x))
```

The problem is that this is relative slow (it takes a whole second!), especially the linking step (since compiling with `-c` or `-S` takes virtually no time, and so does running the outputted binary). One second is not really that slow by itself, but if I were to use this script in other scripts, it would add up.

Is there a faster, less roundabout way to find out what sizes `gcc` uses for datatypes?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, when would you ever need to know the size of a C type when you're not already writing & compiling C code?

Comment: run it once and output to a file, read that file when you need to know

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve the functionality for standard types using the GCC's preprocessor only. For standard types there are predefined macros:

```
__SIZEOF_INT__
__SIZEOF_LONG__
__SIZEOF_LONG_LONG__
__SIZEOF_SHORT__
__SIZEOF_POINTER__
__SIZEOF_FLOAT__
__SIZEOF_DOUBLE__
__SIZEOF_LONG_DOUBLE__
__SIZEOF_SIZE_T__
__SIZEOF_WCHAR_T__
__SIZEOF_WINT_T__
__SIZEOF_PTRDIFF_T__
```

So, by using code like the following:

```
#define TYPE_TO_CHECK __SIZEOF_INT__
#define VAL_TO_STRING(x) #x
#define V_TO_S(x) VAL_TO_STRING(x)
#pragma message V_TO_S(TYPE_TO_CHECK)
#error "terminate"
```

you will be able to get the value of `__SIZEOF_INT__` from the preprocessor itself without even starting the compilation. In your script you can define the `TYPE_TO_CHECK` (with `-D`) to whatever you need and pass it to gcc. Of course you will get some junk output, but I believe you can deal with that.

Comment: I like the idea, although you could just do `echo __SIZEOF_INT__ | cpp | tail -1`.

Comment: This wouldn't be able to calculate the size of arbitrary structures

Comment: @wojtow I can't see a use case based on the question that will inquire about arbitrary structure

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Could just be that you're curious about the effects of padding, no? Maybe you'd like to estimate memory consumption of some algorithm? Who knows.

Comment: @EugeneSh.  true based on original question as long as strictly only the very basic types are needed.   Another minor issue with your approach is that you need to manually translate between the real type names that C uses and the names of the macros  ("void *" = POINTER).  Not a problem if you know what you are looking for, but possibly an added complication if the basic type names passed in from an external source.

Comment: @Wintermute   "cpp" isn't guaranteed to be the same preprocessor used by gcc ... on some systems it is not and potentially could yield different results.    You may want  "gcc -E -" in place of "cpp"

Comment: @wojtow - just to add, the same strategy works with clang: `clang -E -`

Comment: As wojtow pointed out, querying arbitrary structure types would definitely be a plus.

Comment: @Matt The question is asking about making a script/program callable from command line `./sizeof <type>`. How can you pass an arbitrary struct as the `<type>` here?

Comment: In my version of the script, you can do `./sizeof '(struct{int a,b,c,d;char*e[8];}){}'`. I haven't figured out why it needs to be instantiated, though. You can even do `./sizeof 3L` or any other literal.

Comment: Well, I don't see a way of doing this without compilation or some smart parsing.

Comment: I was hoping `gcc` might have some kind of built-in command line option for this. Another idea I was thinking about was to use `gcc -S` and figure out from the assembly code what size things are. That way, no linking would be involved (but a lot of parsing would be).

Comment: Yo can do it, and it is actually not that complicated. `sizeof` is a compile-time operator, so if you put in your file something like `volatile const s = sizeof(struct arbStruct); `, in assembly file you will get something like: `_s:
 .long 16`

Comment: But there is a danger, that your program will run on a platform with totally different assembly directives, so this logic will become invalid.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the 'negative array size' trick that [autoconf](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Generic-Compiler-Characteristics) (see: `AC_COMPUTE_INT`) uses. That way, you don't need to link or execute code. Therefore, it also works when cross compiling. e.g.,

```
int n[1 - 2 * !(sizeof(double) == 8)];
```

fails to compile if: `sizeof(double) != 8`

The downside is, you might have to pass `-DCHECK_SIZE=8` or something similar in the command line, since it might take more than one pass to detect an unusual value. So, I'm not sure if this will be any faster *in general* - but you might be able to take advantage of it.

**Edit:** If you are using gcc exclusively, I think @wintermute's comment is probably the best solution.

Comment: This doesn't output the size, it just checks whether it is 8.

Comment: @Matt - it's up to you to provide a range of values - `AC_COMPUTE_INT` itself implements a binary search to converge on the correct value.

Answer (score 4):

Here are three possible solutions.

The first one will work with any type whose size is less than 256. On my system, it takes about 0.04s (since it doesn't need headers or libraries other than the basic runtime). One downside is that it will only do one at a time, because of the small size of the output channel. Another problem is that it doesn't compensate for slow linking on some systems (notably MinGW):

```
howbig() {
  gcc -x c - <<<'int main() { return sizeof ('$*'); }' && ./a.out
  echo $?
}

$ time howbig "struct { char c; union { double d; int i[3];};}" 
24

real    0m0.041s
user    0m0.031s
sys     0m0.014s

$ time howbig unsigned long long
8

real    0m0.044s
user    0m0.035s
sys     0m0.009s
```

---

If you wanted to be able to do larger types, you could get the size one byte at a time, at the cost of a couple more centiseconds:

```
howbig2 () 
{ 
    gcc -x c - <<< 'int main(int c,char**v) {
                      return sizeof ('$*')>>(8*(**++v&3)); }' &&
    echo $((0x$(printf %02x $(./a.out 3;echo $?) $(./a.out 2;echo $?) \
                            $(./a.out 1;echo $?) $(./a.out 0;echo $?)) ))
}

$ time howbig2 struct '{double d; long long u[12];}([973])'
101192

real    0m0.054s
user    0m0.036s
sys     0m0.019s
```

---

If you are compiling for x86, the following will probably work, although I'm not in a position to test it thoroughly on a wide variety of architectures and platforms. It avoids the link step (notoriously slow on MinGW, for example), by analyzing the compiled assembly output. (It would probably be slightly more robust to analyze the compiled object binary, but I fear that binutils on MinGW are also slow.) Even on Ubuntu, it is significantly faster:

```
howbig3 () { 
  gcc -S -o - -x c - <<< 'int hb(void) { return sizeof ('$*'); }' |
  awk '$1~/movl/&&$3=="%eax"{print substr($2,2,length($2)-2)}'
}

$ time howbig3 struct '{double d; long long u[12];}([973])'
101192

real    0m0.020s
user    0m0.017s
sys     0m0.004s
```

Comment: For me, this is not any faster than what I was doing, since it doesn't eliminate the linking step.

Comment: In case it wasn't clear, it's not linking with the standard library that is the bottleneck, it is the invocation of the linker itself (on my system at least). A simple `int main() { return 0; }` program takes just as long to link.

Comment: @Matt interesting. what system do you have?  I could extract the return value directly from the unlinked object file, but it would be somewhat fragile.

Comment: Windows with cygwin in this case.

Comment: @Matt: MinGW is notoriously slow to link. I added a solution which analyzes the assembly output, but I have no idea how robust it is. Good luck.

Comment: I still think [Eugene's solution in the comments to his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28332806/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-find-the-sizeof-a-type-without-compiling-and-executin/28333350?noredirect=1#comment45042042_28333126) is better, namely: `volatile const s = sizeof(struct arbStruct);`, which would output something like `_s: .long 16` in the assembly (in my case `.comm s, 16, 4`).

Comment: @Matt:Yes, that would be another alternative. It would be harder to detect in the object file. You'd have to try both of them in a lot of compile environments to figure out which one is more robust. Anyway, it's your question :) Select the answer you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

#### Using `nm` with no code

Just make your thing a global variable. `nm` can report its size.

```
// getsize.c

struct foo {
    char str[3];
    short s;     // expect padding galore...
    int i;
} my_struct;
```

Compile but don't link, then use `nm`:

```
$ gcc -c getsize.c
$ nm getsize.o --format=posix
my_struct C 000000000000000c 000000000000000c
```

Note that the last column is the size (in hex), here is how we can get it:

```
$ nm test.o -P | cut -d ' ' -f 4
000000000000000c

# or in decimal
$ printf %d 0x`nm test.o -P | cut -d ' ' -f 4`
12
```

#### Using `objdump` with no code

If `nm` doesn't work for some reason, you can store the *size itself* in a global variable.

Start with this C file:

```
// getsize.c
struct foo { char str[3]; short s; int i; };

unsigned long my_sizeof = sizeof(struct foo);
```

Now we have to find the value of this variable from the object file.

```
$ gcc -c sizeof.c
$ objdump -Sj .data sizeof.o

test.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .data:

0000000000000000 <my_sizeof>:
   0:   0c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                             ........
```

Darn, little endian! You could write a script to parse this, but the following solution (assuming GCC extensions) will force it to always be big endian:

```
// getsize.c
struct foo { char str[3]; short s; int i; };

struct __attribute__ ((scalar_storage_order("big-endian"))) {
    unsigned long v;
} my_sizeof = { sizeof(struct foo) };
```

This yields:

```
0000000000000000 <my_sizeof>:
   0:   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0c                             ........
```

**Watch out!** You can't just strip out all non-hex characters because sometimes the "...." stuff on the right will be valid ASCII. But the first one should always be a `.`. The following command keeps things between the `:` and the first `.`.

```
$ gcc -c sizeof.c
$ objdump -Sj .data sizeof.o |

        sed '$!d                     # keep last line only
             s/\s//g                 # remove tabs and spaces
             s/.*:\([^.]*\)\..*/\1/' # only keep between : and .'

000000000000000c
```

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be in an IDE like VS2019, you can just type `char foo[sizeof(MyType)]` anywhere in the code, hover over `foo` and get the answer :)