# Calculate an arbitrary type's size without executing a program

Tags: c, types, compilation, sizeof

Given any type in a C program, I would like to know it's size, such as one would when executing the following line,

```
printf("%d\n",sizeof(myType));
```

without actually executing the program. The solution must work with arbitrary types whose size can be determined at compile time, such as user-defined structs.

The rationale is that, if it can be known at compile time, there should be a way to extract that information without having to run the program. Possibly something a bit more elegant than having to parse the resulting assembler source or binary for literal contstants, but if that's the only way, I'll take what I can get.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28332806/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-find-the-sizeof-a-type-without-compiling-and-executin) doesn't quite work for me, since OP's solution relies on executing the code, and the most voted answer relies on the preprocessor info directive actually expanding macros (my toolchain doesn't apparently).

For background, I'm developing for PIC18 MCUs and using the XC8 compiler.

Comment: Have a look at the generated assembler code? Otherwise, just read the ABI and gather the information yourself. Sounds like an XY-problem. What do you actually want to achieve? Why do you want to do this? **What** do you want this for?

Comment: You can use the [Compile Time Assertion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/807244/c-compiler-asserts-how-to-implement) for this purpose. Pretty handy.

Comment: The correct way would be a static assertion. Or just nor rely on this, but write correct code, leaving the rest to the compiler.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Please don't direct to non-standard patchwork, if there is a standard version. See `_Static_assert`.

Comment: @Olaf I think it is a new stuff. Not sure PIC18 compiler OP is using will have it. But yeah, that thread might be not a best source.

Comment: Regarding _Static_assert, it seems to be part of the C11 standard. The XC8 compiler in particular does not conform to it (would've been the tool to use otherwise though).

Comment: @DanielArmengod There are ways to implement similar functionality yourself. Or just look around in your toolchain. Pretty sure it has some `assert.h` header..

Comment: @EugeneSh.: I don't see the standard made this optional (other than VLAs). And the question asks about C, which is standard C in the first place. Anyway, if OP uses some outdated compiler, she can ask a new question how to emulate it.

Comment: @Olaf Not every compiler is following the latest standard, and you know it...

Comment: @EugeneSh.: see my edit and the tags along with the info page. That's what comments are for.

Comment: @Olaf. C is something broader than the latest ISO 9899 standard. Same as if you play football with your friends, you play football even if you don't follow the strictest FIFA rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I ultimately want is to verify that some structures I've defined take up their expected size in memory.

This is a classic use case for static assertions. If your compiler supports `_Static_assert`, you can write

```
_Static_assert(sizeof(mystruct) == expected_size, "Invalid struct size.");
```

[demo 1](http://ideone.com/FnS4q5)

If you use an older compiler that does not support C-1x yet, use a common work-around that relies on declaring an array type with negative size:

```
#define CHECK_SIZE(x,e) if(sizeof(char[2*(sizeof(x)==e)-1])==1);
```

[demo 2](http://ideone.com/A3UoB9)

Comment: >`If you use an older compiler that does not support C-1x yet, use a common work-around that relies on declaring an array type with negative size`

Thanks! I thought that might do the trick, so I tried it. Unfortunately, my compiler is not cooperating and will happily compile your _demo2_ code (differences in type size accounted for). It will also do things such as
`struct s { int8_t a; };`
`typedef char pass_assertion[ sizeof(struct s) == 20 ]; //I understand this should yield the null byte`
while it will reject
`typedef char fail_assertion[ 0 ]`

Comment: @DanielArmengod The expression in parentheses is designed to go negative when expression is false. Compilers will take zero-sized arrays, but they must reject arrays of negative size. To try this out with your compiler, make a `typedef char foo[-1];` and see how your compiler reacts.

Comment: My compiler refuses to accept arrays of dimension 0. It generates the following error message: `newmain.c:3: error: (284) invalid dimension` (tested with `typedef char a[0]`)

Comment: @DanielArmengod What happens if you write the same without an `if`, i.e. `#define CHECK_SIZE(x,e) typedef char size_check[2*(sizeof(x)==e)-1]`?

Comment: The last suggestion works! Thank you! I really don't understand why it doesn't work inside an if condition. I did some testing and found out that it will work properly if the variable being tested has a basic type (e.g. char, long), however if it is of type `struct X`, then whatever that struct is and whatever size you're checking against, it will never trigger.