# What's the best way to setup a lookup table when indexes aren't sequential?

Tags: c

I have two enums defined thusly

```
enum foo {
    foo_a = 0x1,
    foo_b = 0x2,
    foo_c = 0x4,
    foo_d = 0x8,
    foo_e = 0x10,
    ..etc..
}
```

and

```
enum bar {
    bar_a = 0x1,
    bar_b = 0x2,
    bar_c = 0x4,
    bar_d = 0x8,
    bar_e = 0x10,
    ..etc..
}
```

Now, there's a 1 to 1 mapping between foo_[az] and bar_[az], and I'd like to look it up quickly.  The obvious way to do this is to do something declare something like

```
int table[][] = {
    [foo_a] = bar_c,
    [foo_b] = bar_a,
    [foo_c] = bar_b,
    ..etc..
}
```

and just look it up using `result = table[(enum foo)temp]`.  But since these enums have been declared bitwise, the size of `table` grows exponentially.

Is there a simpler way to set things up at compile time?

One thing I considered doing something like

```
int table[][] = {
    [LOG(foo_a)] = bar_c,
    [LOG(foo_b)] = bar_a,
    [LOG(foo_c)] = bar_b,
    ..etc..
}
```

which would reduce the memory footprint, but I'm not aware of anyway to compute LOG at compile time.

Any other suggestions?

My only restriction is the following, I can't modify the enums in anyway because changing them would result in binary incompatibility.

Edit: Compile-time solutions preferred

Comment: Before you consider a shortcut to this, I have to ask, What are you planning on "looking up" *with* when presented a multi-bit value such as (foo_a|foo_b) (which is the only logical reason for using bit-columns as your proposing in the first place)?

Comment: Do the enums really have the *same* possible values? Could you just cast a variable from one enum type to another?

Comment: @WhozCraig the API actually wasn't designed correctly.  The values were never meant to |'ed together.  I don't understand why they never bothered to number them sequentially in the first place.

Comment: @chrisaycock No, as I mentioned in the example. foo_a (0x1) could be mapped to bar_c (0x4), so casting doesn't work.  That and to keep things simple, I sorta lied about the 1 to 1 mapping.  There are elements in foo that aren't mapped to bar, and there are elements in bar not mapped to.  But each element mapped to a unique element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can "compute log at compile time" as long as the argument is a power of two:

```
#define LOG2P2(m) (((m)-1)/(((m)-1)%255+1) / 255%255*8 + 7-86/(((m)-1)%255+12))
```

This works for values of `m` up to around 2**2040 (much larger than any type on a real-world C implementation) and there's a version that works for even larger values where I got this one from, in the answer to the following question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4589384/379897

Comment: Thanks!  Digging further, I came upon the linux kernel's more decipherable implementation ilog2 @ http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/log2.h .  This is somewhat convenient since I'm writing a driver anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Just make a table of pairs:

```
int table[2][] = {
  { foo_a, bar_c },
  { foo_b, bar_a },
  /* ... */
};
```

Now sort it, and if you want, copy it to a second table which is sorted by the second value to do the reverse lookup.  Then do linear search if the table is only a dozen elements, or use `bsearch()` if it's large.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the value of all the enums then you can calculate the log of all the enums and store them in a buffer. Or, you can write all the log. values (you are going to use) in a file and read that file to generate the table; in that way you will calculate the log. values only for the first time.