# LONG_BIT in limits.h

Tags: c

I'm writing a program for my study and therefore I have to descripe a few wars to get the limits of some data types.
When I'm writing this:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", CHAR_BIT);
    printf("%d\n", LONG_BIT);
    return 0;
}
```

but it gives me the following error:

```
a.c: In function ‘main’:
a.c:7:17: error: ‘LONG_BIT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  printf("%d\n", LONG_BIT);
                 ^
a.c:7:17: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

even gcc -E gives me this

```
int main(void)
{
 printf("%d\n", 8);
 printf("%d\n", LONG_BIT);
 return 0;
}
```

But a grep in limits.h doesn't give me the answer. But bits/xopen_lim.h has this declaration and it should be included when

```
__USE_XOPEN
```

is declared, but even a manual declaration won't give me a result.

So where is the problem? A look in the manpage says there is a LONG_BIT macro but gcc says no.

gcc version 4.8.0 (GCC)
OS arch

[edit]
For those who say LONG_BIT is not a c-standard, type

```
man 0 limits.h
```

and search for LONG_BIT. For me there are two entries under **Numerical Limits** and therefore I think LONG_BIT exist.
And no, including bits/xopen_lim.h is not realy an option, because it should be included by limits.h and not manually

Comment: did you manually include the header xopen_lim.h?

Comment: What your manpage tells you is not the same as standard C...

Comment: But when there is a entry in the man page, why does it not work? It's like you write a book and say the sun turns around the earth, although is does not ;)

Comment: @cookiesoft: I have no idea what the problem is with your particular setup ;)  But IMO, you should prefer the platform-independent approach, as it's trivial!

Comment: its not that it doesnt work. it that portability is what your giving up with your approach

Comment: Using well defined POSIX standards isn't exactly giving up portability.

Comment: @teppic: Well it is if you also want to compile on non-POSIX systems ;)

Comment: It's not about portabilty, it's not about doing something special, it's just a question with an example ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you shouldn't be defining `__USE_XOPEN`.  If you take a look at [`/usr/include/features.h`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;f=include/features.h;hb=glibc-2.30#l42) you will see it explicitly undefines it and then redefines these macros based on feature test macros.  You probably want to define `_XOPEN_SOURCE` instead, something like:

```
gcc -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700 -o longbit longbit.c
```

From `features.h`:

> _XOPEN_SOURCE        Includes POSIX and XPG things.  Set to 500 if
>                           Single Unix conformance is wanted, to 600 for the
>                           sixth revision, to 700 for the seventh revision.
>   _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED XPG things and X/Open Unix
>   extensions.

Also, wrt directly including `xopen_lim.h`:

```
/*
 * Never include this file directly; use <limits.h> instead.
 */
```

So, I wouldn't recommend directly including it. Also, see [`man feature_test_macros`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html) or [`info '(libc)Feature Test Macros'`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html).

Answer (score 2):

`LONG_BIT` is not a thing in **standard** C.

For a portable approach, just do this:

```
CHAR_BIT * sizeof(long)
```

Comment: Downvoted: This is *NOT* portable, that is why LONG_BIT is necessary. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957252.

Comment: @Loic - This isn't clear.  Firstly, it sounds like you're claiming that `LONG_BIT` is *more* portable (even though it's not a standard thing).  Secondly, I struggle to understand what part of it is non-portable (in a way that `LONG_BIT` would fix on platforms where it does exist).

Comment: The size of an integer (which you suggested) is **greater than or equal to** its width. How to compute the width is explained in: stackoverflow.com/questions/3957252. With "LONG_BIT is necessary", I meant any macro for the suitable value; LONG_BIT is non-standard, indeed. See also https://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Import-and-Export.html#Integer-Import-and-Export: "However on Cray vector systems it may be noted that short and int are always stored in 8 bytes (and with sizeof indicating that) but use only 32 or 46 bits.".

Comment: @loic - That's not possible. log2(x) is never greater than x (where x is the maximum possible value of a type).

Comment: @loic: also bear in mind that whether it's greater than the size of the type is irrelevant. sizeof(x) returns a size_t, not the type of x.

Comment: Your last arguments are irrelevant to the question. Your original suggestion is just not portable (but happens to work on common hardware). According to the documentation of gmp: On Cray vector systems, the *size* (in bits) of an int is *64*, but the *width* (in bits) of an int is only *46*. Or, for the sake of using logarithms: size == log2(2^64) > log2(2^46) == width. This definition may help: For the width of a given unsigned type, the maximal value of this type is 2^width-1. See also: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/INT35-C.+Use+correct+integer+precisions.

Comment: @Loic - Yup you're right - I misinterpreted your "greater than or equal to its width" statement as being about overflow (as suggested in the linked question).  If the aim is to get the width (and not the size) then I agree this approach isn't going to work on any platform with padding bits.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/

There is nothing as such `LONG_BIT` in `limits.h`

Comment: I wouldn't use cplusplus.com as a reference for anything.  http://cppreference.com is substantially more accurate.  But the C standard is the ultimate reference.

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/limits.h.html     
http://www.unix.com/man-page/opensolaris/3head/limits.h/