# How to assign a specific array size in C header file

Tags: c, arrays, header-files

I have a constant called A defined in a header file; it is always an even number.

I would like to declare an array B in the same header file whose length depends on the value of A.

For example;

If A is 32, I would like the array size to be 4, (2,4,8,16 being the elements. All powers of 2 till A/2).

If A is 48, I would like the array size to be 5, (2,4,8,16,24 being the elements. All powers of 2 till A/2 and the last element being A/2).

What is an elegant way to calculate the array size of B given a value of A using the above logic?

Comment: Why do you have to declare the array statically. This sounds like something that requires calculation and dynamic allocation.

Comment: i want the array declared in the header becuse i will use it across multiple c files.

Comment: You can define it in one module and export it using 'extern'

Comment: @OmerEldan Can you give an example and post it as an answer please

Comment: The size of the array needs to be floor(log2(A-1)), I think.  Expressing that as a compile-time computable constant value is not trivial.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler is there a trivial bound which I can use such that floor(log2(A-1)) is always less than that.

Comment: Is there an upper bound on A?  If A is 256 or less, then floor(log2(A-1)) is 7, I think.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I was thinking more on the lines of a easily defined bound depending on A. But yeah I could use a hard bound for all A. For now max A is 512 but may change.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler is there an inbuilt function in C to calculate log base 2

Comment: OK; your array isn't exactly going to be huge (63) if your value of A goes up to 18446744073709551615 (maximum size of an unsigned 64-bit integer), so you can put a bound of 63 on your array.  More realistically, you could probably choose 16 and have oodles of room for growth.

Comment: Only for floating point, which is why it is non-trivial — you'd use `log()` from `<math.h>`.  You also can't use functions for initializers in variables at file scope or static in a function; only for automatic variables.  You might do worse than `A <= 4 ? 1 : A <= 8 ? 2 : A <= 16 ? 3 : A <= 32 ? 4 : A <= 64 ? 5 : …`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a `#define` for `A`, but given that you do that, you can manage using some scheme like this:

```
#define A 384

#define B_SIZE (A <= 16 ? 3 : A <= 32 ? 4 : A <= 64 ? 5 : A <= 128 ? 6 : \
                A <= 256 ? 7 : A <= 512 ? 8 : A <= 1024 ? 9 : -1)

extern int B[B_SIZE];
```

The use of `-1` as the tail value is not accidental; it ensures a compilation error because you can't have arrays with a negative size, so if `A` is too big, the code won't compile.  You could use the same trick to rule out sizes that are too small, too.

In the code that defines and initializes the array, you use:

```
int B[B_SIZE] =
{
    2, 4,
#if A > 16
    8,
#endif
#if A > 32
    16,
#endif
#if A > 64
    32,
#endif
#if A > 128
    64,
#endif
#if A > 256
    128,
#endif
#if A > 512
    256,
#endif
    A/2
};
```

This isn't elegant, but I'm not sure there's a neater way to do it.  This uses `B_SIZE` explicitly again to ensure a compilation error again if the value of `A` is out of bounds.  You could otherwise just leave the `B_SIZE` out of the array specification.

You could easily write a shell (Awk, Perl, Python, …) script to generate the code up to a given size.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I am missing something. Why don't you simply define the array as:

```
int array[] = {
   2,4,8,16
#if A == 48
   ,24
#endif
};

#define DIM_OF_ARRAY (sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]))
```

Comment: But note that this should be defined this way in a C source file. The header should contain only `int array[];`.

Answer (score 1):

If we can limit `A` to always be a power of two, then this is related to another problem: *"How do you compute the number of value bits in an integer type at compile time?"* This problem was solved beautifully by **Hallvard B Furuseth** more than a decade ago. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4589384/3478852

Using Hallvard's solution, we can compute the array size as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Number of bits in inttype_MAX, or in any (1<<k)-1 where 0 <= k < 2040 */
#define IMAX_BITS(m) ((m)/((m)%255+1) / 255%255*8 + 7-86/((m)%255+12))

#define A 1073741824

int B[IMAX_BITS(A/2-1)];

int main (void)
{
  printf ("%d\n", (int)(sizeof B / sizeof B[0]));
  return 0;
}
```

Note:

- The number `A` **must** be a power of two.
- The code uses the simpler version of the macro that is only accurate up to 2039 bits. There is another version in the article for ridiculously large numbers.

Comment: Interesting, but not all that relevant since the question explicitly mentions that `A` could have the value 48, which is not a power of 2.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Dang, I missed that part. Actually I did read it, but forgot all about it.

Comment: Rephrased the presumption in the answer.