# 1U<<32 is 1, am I misunderstood C standard or GCC (Clang, MSVC) buggy?

Tags: c

There is something different with 1U << 32 and first assign 32 to a variable (for example, n) then left shift n. I tried with `printf("%u\n", 1U << 32)`, compilers will optimize the result to 0. But when I try this code,

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int n = 32;
    printf("%u\n", 1U << n);
}
```

Compiling and executing the code above will print the result of 1.

According to C/C++ standard,

> The value of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated bits are zero-filled. If E1 has an unsigned type, the value of the result is E1×2^E2, reduced modulo one more than the maximum value representable in the result type. Otherwise, if E1 has a signed type and non-negative value, and E1×2^E2 is representable in the corresponding unsigned type of the result type, then that value, converted to the result type, is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

In my opnion, when E1 is unsigned and E1 << E2 overflows, the result will be E1 * 2 ^ E2 mod (UINT_MAX + 1), so the result of 1U << n should be 0.

But compiling with GCC 4.4 to 7.2 or Clang 3.1 to 5.0 on x86 and ARM gave the result of 1. I checked the assembly code and found both produced the following assembly,

```
movl   $20,-0x4(%rbp)
mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
mov    $0x1,%edx
mov    %eax,%ecx
shl    %cl,%edx
```

and

```
orr     w8, wzr, #0x1
orr     w9, wzr, #0x20
stur    w9, [x29, #-4]
ldur    w9, [x29, #-4]
lsl     w1, w8, w9
```

And then I checked the instruction `shl` and `lsl`, on [c9x.me](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_285.html) I found following description about `shl`,

> The destination operand can be a register or a memory location. The count operand can be an immediate value or register CL. The count is masked to 5 bits, which limits the count range to 0 to 31.

And assembler guide of ARM tells that the `lsl`'s allowed shifts is 0-31.

It means at least the instruction `shl` works well, that is the reason why I suspect the implementation of compilers are wrong, but it seems impossible to have such a bug for so wide and long, could any one explain to me?

Thanks.

Comment: First of all, for semantic rules you should only specify one language. C and C++ are two *very* different languages. And their standards are *very* different as well, with different wording even for similar things.

Comment: "assembler guide of ARM tells that the lsl's allowed shifts is 0-31" and "The count is masked to 5 bits" means that your 32 became 0, so no shift is performed.

Comment: `<stdio>` is neither C nor C++. Could be this new "C/C++" language I keep hearing about.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shifting unsigned int more than the size of it, undefined or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45432694/shifting-unsigned-int-more-than-the-size-of-it-undefined-or-not)

Comment: Sorry for `<stdio>`, I misspelled it.

Comment: But you do reference the "C/C++ standard". Have found this super secret document?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The operands shall be of integral or unscoped enumeration type and integral promotions are performed. The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand. ***The behavior is undefined*** if the right operand is negative, ***or greater than or equal to the length in bits of the promoted left operand.***

C++11, §5.8 ¶1 (emphasis added)

> The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand. If the value of the right operand is negative or ***is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined***.

C99, §6.5.7 ¶3 (emphasis added)

It's extremely likely that these rules were made exactly because the shift operators on existing platforms had this kind of limitations; without this rule in place, every shift of an unknown value would have to be transformed to code more complex than a simple underlying platform shift instruction, while it's expected for shifts to be extremely fast operations.

Answer (score 0):

noting: *The destination operand can be a register or a memory location. The count operand can be an immediate value or register CL. The count is masked to 5 bits, which limits the count range to 0 to 31.*

the value 32 is:  0x00000020

limited to 5 bits is: 0x00000000

1 << 0 results in 1