# How to efficiently enumerate a Restricted Gray Code?

Tags: c, combinatorics, enumeration

I'm looking for an algorithm which enumeration all binary strings of length `n` in a Gray code manner, with the restriction that all strings have at most hamming weight `<= k`. For example `n=4,k=2`:

```
0000
0001
0011
0010
0110
---- skipped
0101
0100
1100
---- skipped
---- skipped
---- skipped
1010
---- skipped
1001
1000
```

`n` and `k` are known constants. The classic Gray code has two very important features: One can simply compute the `i`-th element `a` as `i ^ (i >> 1)` and given the `i`-th element `a` one can compute the next one as `a ^ ctz(i+1)`, where `ctz` returns the number of trailing zeros (gcc buildin function).

So im looking for something like a "restricted" Gray code, with this features, which should be easy and fast computable.

The most straight forward solution would be to insert a `popcount` into the loop, which branches if a code word has the wrong weight. Sadly this is far to expensive in my setting: `n = 45-50` and `k = 15-18`.

Comment: You mentioned `n = 45-50` and `k = 15-18`. Are those absolute [maximums]? (i.e.) The gray codes you're interested in will always fit in 64 bits? Do you have working C code [that uses `popcount`] and a test program? For another project, I came up with an alternate way to generate gray codes. It used decimal (or _any_ base) digits. Think: odometer than only changes one digit at a time. It could eliminate the repeated use of `popcount`. But, to see if it's applicable, and to see if it's any faster, it would help to have a working code from you that I could compare it against.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is what you're looking for but let's give it a try...

The ith element of the code is calculated using the formula you mentioned:
`G[i] = i ^ (i >> 1)`. Another feature of the Gray code is that any element is different from the previous one in a single place, therefore the bitwise xor operation between an element `G[i]` and its predecessor `G[i-1]`, will result in a single bit being equal to one, at the position `d` at which the two element are different from each other. For instance `G[i] ^ G[i-1] = 0101 ^ 0111 = 0010`. Now the bitwise and operation between this result and the element `G[i]`, will give 0 only if `G[i]` has a 0 at position `d`, otherwise the result will be equal to `2 ^ d`, with `d` starting from 0. So, if `(G[i] ^ G[i-1]) & G[i] == 0` it means that at the only place the two elements differ, `G[i]` has a 0 instead of a 1 and therefore its Hamming weight is 1 less than the one of `G[i-1]`. On the other hand if `(G[i] ^ G[i-1]) & G[i] != 0`, the Hamming weight of `G[i]` is 1 more than the one of `G[i-1]`. In order to know the Hamming weight of an element you just have to keep track of the weight of the previous elements. Starting from 0 and adding or subtracting 1 each time based on the result of `(G[i] ^ G[i-1]) & G[i]`. Hopefully this is somewhat comprehensible...

At a first glance I would say that this should perform better than the version using `popcount` but it may also depend on how operations are implemented both in software and hardware. I'm not particularly expert in this regard.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void printBinary(uint64_t number);   // function for printing the variable in binary

int main()
{
    int k = 18;       // max Hamming weight
    int iter = 1000;  // number of codes to check

    uint64_t Gnew = 0;
    uint64_t Gold = 0;

    int i = 0;
    int count = 0;   // counter holding the Hamming weight of the current element

    printBinary(Gold);   // print the first element (0)

    for (i = 1; i < iter; i++){

        Gnew = i ^ (i >> 1);   // generate the ith element of the Gray code

        if (((Gnew ^ Gold) & Gnew) != 0){   // checks if the new element has one 1 more than the previous
            count++;                        // and increases the counter
        }else{          // or has one 1 less
            count--;    // and decreases the counter
        }
        if(count <= k){    // if element has weight smaller or equal to k print the element
            printBinary(Gnew);
        }

        Gold = Gnew;
    }

    return 0;
}

void printBinary(uint64_t number)    // from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47326588/c-print-unsigned-int-in-a-binary-base
                                     // with some modifications
{
    int i;

    for(i = 63; i >= 0; i--){
        if(number >> i & 0x1){
                putchar('1');
        }else{
            putchar('0');
        }
    }

    putchar('\n');

    return;
}
```