# Why isn't there an INT_BIT?

Tags: c, posix

Why are there `_BIT` macros in `limits.h` for `CHAR_BIT`, `LONG_BIT`, `WORD_BIT`? Why doesn't it define an `INT_BIT`?

Is there a reason why these macros are defined for other types, but not for `int`? Are these deprecated (out of use) with `sizeof`?

I see these are defined by [POSIX for `limits.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/limits.h.html)

Comment: Because `sizeof(anything)*CHAR_BIT = ANYTHING_BIT`

Comment: @EugeneSh. yea, that what I was thinking. if you want to make that an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Only `CHAR_BIT` is standard. Vendor-specific `LONG_BIT` and `WORD_BIT` either have slightly different meanings, or are nonsense.

Comment: There is no mentioning about `LONG_BIT` or `WORD_BIT` in C standard.

Comment: @EugeneSh. it's in POSIX.

Comment: "Why doesn't it define an INT_BIT?" --> perhaps the question should be why is the "Number of bits in an object of type int." defined as `WORD_BIT`  and not `INT_BIT` ?

Comment: I googled and found (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/limits.h.html). Quote: "{LONG_BIT} Number of bits in a long. Minimum Acceptable Value: 32". That doesn't seem compatible with a notion of slightly useful `LONG_BIT` as the number of value representation bits, the *width*.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: That's from SUS, which imposes the additional requirement that there are no bits *other* than value representation bits.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, do you have an intended uses case for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `WORD_BIT` is what you want to be `INT_BIT`, from the document you link to:

> `{WORD_BIT}` Number of bits in an object of **type `int`.**

Note that `CX` means this is an extension to standard C.

The [C99 rationale document](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) tells us the committee saw little reason for anything besides `CHAR_BIT`:

> The macro `CHAR_BIT` makes available the number of bits in a char object. The C89 **Committee saw little utility in adding such macros for other data types**.

likely because `CHAR_BIT*sizeof(type)` does what you need.

Comment: Except it does not work with conditional compilation.

Comment: @Ivan can you provide an example where you can't create a macro you need from standard C? It does not change the answer since that is the rationale provided and that won't change but I don't see it.

Comment: Preprocessor cannot evaluate `sizeof` operator. `#if CHAR_BIT*sizeof(type)` won't be able to go through preprocessor stage.

Comment: @Ivan so why not just `#define BLAH CHAR_BIT*sizeof(type)` then and use that?

Comment: My point is that this cannot be used with conditional compilation, for example when there is a need to select some datatype at compile time.

Comment: Except in the very theoretical scenario when `type` has padding bits.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate them at build time by counting the bits in the corresponding unsigned maximum.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int popcnt(unsigned long long X) { int pc=0;for(;(X&1);pc++,X>>=1){;} return pc; }
int main()
{
    if(0>printf("#define CHAR_BIT %d\n", popcnt(UCHAR_MAX))) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    if(0>printf("#define UCHAR_BIT %d\n", popcnt(UCHAR_MAX))) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    if(0>printf("#define SCHAR_BIT %d\n", popcnt(UCHAR_MAX))) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    if(0>printf("#define SHRT_BIT %d\n", popcnt(USHRT_MAX))) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    if(0>printf("#define USHRT_BIT %d\n", popcnt(USHRT_MAX))) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    if(0>printf("#define INT_BIT %d\n", popcnt(UINT_MAX))) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    if(0>printf("#define UINT_BIT %d\n", popcnt(UINT_MAX))) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    if(0>printf("#define LONG_BIT %d\n", popcnt(ULONG_MAX))) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    if(0>printf("#define ULONG_BIT %d\n", popcnt(ULONG_MAX))) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    if(0>printf("#define LLONG_BIT %d\n", popcnt(ULLONG_MAX))) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    if(0>printf("#define ULLONG_BIT %d\n", popcnt(ULLONG_MAX))) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    if(0>fclose(stdout)) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

On my platform, the above gets me:

```
#define CHAR_BIT 8
#define UCHAR_BIT 8
#define SCHAR_BIT 8
#define SHRT_BIT 16
#define USHRT_BIT 16
#define INT_BIT 32
#define UINT_BIT 32
#define LONG_BIT 64
#define ULONG_BIT 64
#define LLONG_BIT 64
#define ULLONG_BIT 64
```

(Note that these are not technically guaranteed to be `sizeof(the_type)*CHAR_BIT` as the C standard allows for padding bits in the native types.)

If running this piece of code before before building on any platform you want to support is annoying to you, I get you.

Using this little shell script, you can generate (once for every platform) a perfectly integer-constant-expression-preserving no-UB-invoking (hopefully) `popcnt` cpp-macro for up to N-bit integers:

```
#!/bin/sh -eu
gen()
{
    Max=$1
    local i=0;
    prev='(X)'
    #continuous popcount at compile time
    printf '#define contpopcnt(X) %s\n' "(($prev&1)\\"
    i=1; while [ $i -le $Max ]; do
        #look 1 bit ahead the left shift never reaches or exceeds 
        #the width of whatever X's type might be (would be UB)
        prev="(($prev&2)?((X)>>$i):0)"
        printf '+(%s&1)\\\n' "$prev"
    i=$((i+1));done
    printf ')\n'
}

gen 256
cat<<EOF
//#define CHAR_BIT contpopcnt(UCHAR_MAX)
#define UCHAR_BIT contpopcnt(UCHAR_MAX)
#define SCHAR_BIT contpopcnt(UCHAR_MAX)
#define SHRT_BIT contpopcnt(USHRT_MAX)
#define USHRT_BIT contpopcnt(USHRT_MAX)
#define INT_BIT contpopcnt(UINT_MAX)
#define UINT_BIT contpopcnt(UINT_MAX)
#define LONG_BIT contpopcnt(ULONG_MAX)
#define ULONG_BIT contpopcnt(ULONG_MAX)
#define LLONG_BIT contpopcnt(ULLONG_MAX)
#define ULLONG_BIT contpopcnt(ULLONG_MAX)

//a little sanity check
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#if CHAR_BIT!=contpopcnt(UCHAR_MAX)
    #error "oops"
#endif
EOF
```

And the 256-bit variant of the macro is only (!) 605KB. So you don't really need those `*_BIT` macros.

Edit:

A much more compact way over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4589384/1084774.