# CHAR_WIDTH undeclared

Tags: c, gcc

I get the error 
`‘CHAR_WIDTH’ undeclared`
when I try to compile this simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
  printf("CHAR_BIT = %d\n", CHAR_BIT);
  printf("CHAR_WIDTH = %d\n", CHAR_WIDTH);
  return (0);
}
```

with

```
gcc ./show_char_width.c -o show_char_width
```

and gcc: GNU C17 (Ubuntu 8.3.0-6ubuntu1) version 8.3.0 (x86_64-linux-gnu) compiled by GNU C version 8.3.0, GMP version 6.1.2, MPFR version 4.0.2, MPC version 1.1.0, isl version isl-0.20-GMP,
kernel: 5.0.0-37-generic.

As stated [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Width-of-Type.html) CHAR_WIDTH should be defined in limits.h which is included in my program. So why I get this error?

With the `-v` option I found that the library will be searched in those directories:

```
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
```

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/include-fixed contain a limits.h that include syslimits.h from the same dir which in turn include the next limits.h, that from my understanding should be located in the /usr/include directory.

The CHAR_WIDTH macro is indeed defined in those files but under some conditions that exceed my actual knowledge.

The conditions I found untill now are:

```
/* The integer width macros are not defined by GCC's <limits.h> before
   GCC 7, or if _GNU_SOURCE rather than
   __STDC_WANT_IEC_60559_BFP_EXT__ is used to enable this feature.  */
#if __GLIBC_USE (IEC_60559_BFP_EXT)
# ifndef CHAR_WIDTH
#  define CHAR_WIDTH 8
# endif
```

and :

```
#ifdef __STDC_WANT_IEC_60559_BFP_EXT__
/* TS 18661-1 widths of integer types.  */
# undef CHAR_WIDTH
# define CHAR_WIDTH __SCHAR_WIDTH__
```

That's why I need your help.

Note: I get the same error with all other macros described in A.5.1 notably: SCHAR_WIDTH, INT_WIDTH, LONG_WIDTH, etc.

Comment: Which kind of conditions?

Comment: ```
/* The integer width macros are not defined by GCC's <limits.h> before
   GCC 7, or if _GNU_SOURCE rather than
   __STDC_WANT_IEC_60559_BFP_EXT__ is used to enable this feature.  */
#if __GLIBC_USE (IEC_60559_BFP_EXT)
# ifndef CHAR_WIDTH
#  define CHAR_WIDTH 8
# endif```

Comment: @LP: probably some that the OP does not understand --> "*exceed my actual knowledge.*"

Comment: @alk I was (not so directly) asking to post that part of code...

Comment: I edited the post with some code from /usr/include/limits.h

Comment: After the edit. define `__STDC_WANT_IEC_60559_BFP_EXT__` or pass it by command line

Comment: FWIW, POSIX requires `CHAR_BIT` to be 8, which should mean `CHAR_WIDTH` must also be 8 on POSIX systems.

Comment: @LPs I added ```#define __STDC_WANT_IEC_60559_BFP_EXT__ ``` but got the same error

Comment: @pliski did you `#define` before the `#include`?

Comment: pass `-D__STDC_WANT_IEC_60559_BFP_EXT__` to the compiler.

Comment: @LegendofPedro Yes sir it's work. If we define before the headers file. https://wandbox.org/permlink/yms2Ww8GbnG3zgnU

Comment: Try compiling with `-std=gnu11` or similar? (In ISO C these macros cannot be defined by the implementation as they are not reserved identifiers)

Comment: @LegendofPedro you're right ... my bad!

Comment: @LPs Could to post the answer?

Comment: @M.M gcc -std=gnu11 ./show_char_width.c -o show_char_width does not work for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CHAR_WIDTH` isn't standard, nor are any other `*_WIDTH` macros, but the width of a character type must be the same as `CHAR_BIT` anyway*.

As for `*_WIDTH` macros in general, they aren't strictly needed as they are compile-time-computable from the maximum value of the corresponding unsigned type, i.e., you can have a `#define WIDTH_FROM_UNSIGNED_MAX(UnsignedMax)` that expands to an integer constant expression that's also usable in preprocessor conditionals (`#if`), though implementations are a little bit obscure (see [Is there any way to compute the width of an integer type at compile-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957252/is-there-any-way-to-compute-the-width-of-an-integer-type-at-compile-time/4589384#4589384)), e.g.:

```
#define WIDTH_FROM_UNSIGNED_MAX(UnsignedMax) POW2_MINUS1_BITS_2039(UnsignedMax)
/* Number of bits in inttype_MAX, or in any (1<<k)-1 where 0 <= k < 2040 */
#define POW2_MINUS1_BITS_2039(X) ((X)/((X)%255+1) / 255%255*8 + 7-86/((X)%255+12))

//compile-time test it, assuming uint{8,16,32,64}_t exist
#include <inttypes.h>
#if WIDTH_FROM_UNSIGNED_MAX(UINT8_MAX) != 8
    #error
#endif
#if WIDTH_FROM_UNSIGNED_MAX(UINT16_MAX) != 16
    #error
#endif
#if WIDTH_FROM_UNSIGNED_MAX(UINT32_MAX) != 32
    #error
#endif
#if WIDTH_FROM_UNSIGNED_MAX(UINT64_MAX) != 64
    #error
#endif
```

Some people just do `CHAR_BIT * sizeof(integer_type)`, but that isn't strictly *portable*, because it assumes `integer_type` doesn't have padding bits (it usually doesn't but theoretically it can have them), and can't use it in `#if` conditionals either.

---

*Unfortunately, to glean this info, you need jump all over the standard:

The width of an integer type is (slightly indirectly) defined as the number of its nonpadding bits ([6.2.6.2p6](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.6.2p6)).

[6.2.6.2p2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.6.2p2) says `signed char` doesn't have any padding bits. Because of how integers can be represented in C ([6.2.6.2p2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.6.2p2)), that implies `unsigned char` can't have any padding bits either, and since `char` must have the same limits as either `signed char` or `unsigned char` ([5.2.4.2.1p2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.2.1p2)) while having the same `sizeof` value (namely 1, [6.5.3.4p4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.4p4)), a plain `char` can't have any padding bits either, and so `CHAR_BIT` *== width of (`char`|`signed char`|`unsigned char`)*.