# C printf: Is there a way to add text after variable and before spacing?

Tags: c, printf

I want to create output like this using printf:

```
Name          Available         Required
------------- ----------------- ---------------
Something     10.1 GiB          2.3 GiB
```

But using the built-in spacing mechanism doesn't allow to add a measurement text (ie Gb) ***after*** the variable, ***before*** the space. The issue is that this text needs to be included in the spacing. I have tried

```
"%-12.1f GiB"
```

Which puts "GiB" after the spacing.

Comment: Please show exactly what your code outputs, instead of describing the result. Also show the exact code that generates the result.

Comment: It would indeed be easier to have this *right-aligned*; otherwise you need to sprintf the component strings and use `%s` with the width specifier

Comment: @EugeneSh .Seems quite clear: both the number (`10.1` or `2.3` and the units `Gb` together in one padded-to-12 string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `printf` function won’t do this in one shot. Use an intermediate string.

```
double gigabytes_avail;
char buf[64];
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%.1f GB", gigabytes_avail);

printf("%-12s", buf);
```

If you are using Visual Studio and its compiler you may consider using `sprintf_s()` instead of `snprintf()`. They are not the same function, but `sprintf_s()` is suitable here.

Alternatively, you can do the padding yourself, since `printf` returns the number of characters written…

```
int column_width = 15;
double gigabytes_avail;
// Does not handle errors, printf may return -1.
int r = printf("%.1f GB", gigabytes_avail);
for (; r < column_width; r++) {
    putchar(' ');
}
```

As a minor note, the symbol for gigabyte is GB, not Gb. Gigabit is Gbit.

Comment: +1, but as far as I can see, the OP never mention _bytes_... it could displaying network capacity in gigabits...

Comment: Gigabits isn’t Gb either.

Comment: To well handle all `double` with `"%.1f GB"`, suggest `buf[(1 /* sign */ + DBL_MAX_10_EXP + 1 /* '.' */ + 1  /* frac */) + 3 + 1]` or typically about 315.  Of course OP has other troubles should `gigabytes_avail` get excessive.

Comment: 64 bytes overflows somewhere around the time you have 1GB available for each atom in the *sun,* according to my math.

Comment: True about valid `gigabytes_avail`, more of a concern with errant values causing other issues and as an example of how to handle all `double`.

Answer (score 3):

`printf` returns the number of characters printed.
Use that value from one `printf` to pad the subsequent `printf`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( void) {

    printf ( "Name          Available         Required\n");
    printf ( "------------- ----------------- ---------------\n");

    for ( int out = 0; out < 20; out += 3) {
        printf ( "%-15s", "Something");
        int span = printf ( "%5.1f Gb", out * 10.1);
        printf ( "%*.1f Gb\n", 22 - span, out * 2.3);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Name          Available         Required
------------- ----------------- ---------------
Something        0.0 Gb           0.0 Gb
Something       30.3 Gb           6.9 Gb
Something       60.6 Gb          13.8 Gb
Something       90.9 Gb          20.7 Gb
Something      121.2 Gb          27.6 Gb
Something      151.5 Gb          34.5 Gb
Something      181.8 Gb          41.4 Gb
```

A few edits will produce fully left justified results.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( void) {

    printf ( "Name          Available         Required\n");
    printf ( "------------- ----------------- ---------------\n");

    for ( int out = 0; out < 20; out += 3) {
        printf ( "%-14s", "Something");
        int span = printf ( "%.1f Gb", out * 10.1);
        printf ( "%*c%.1f Gb\n", 18 - span, ' ', out * 2.3);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Fully left justified results:

```
Name          Available         Required
------------- ----------------- ---------------
Something     0.0 Gb            0.0 Gb
Something     30.3 Gb           6.9 Gb
Something     60.6 Gb           13.8 Gb
Something     90.9 Gb           20.7 Gb
Something     121.2 Gb          27.6 Gb
Something     151.5 Gb          34.5 Gb
Something     181.8 Gb          41.4 Gb
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it is fun to create a reusable, even in a `printf()` line, as macro/function to handle a wide range of values.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/4589384/2410359
#define IMAX_BITS(m) ((m)/((m)%255+1) / 255%255*8 + 7-86/((m)%255+12))

// Decimal digits possible in an integer `m`    
#define IMAX_DIGITS(m) (IMAX_BITS(m)*28/93 + 1) //ceiling( bits * log10(2))

#define ULLONG_STRING_SIZE (IMAX_DIGITS(ULLONG_MAX) + 1)
#define KSCALE 1000u /* or 1024u */

char* PrintMetric(char *dest, size_t n, unsigned long long b, char *suffix) {
  char prefix[] = "\0kMGTPEZY";
  int i = 0;
  while (i < sizeof prefix - 1 && b / pow(KSCALE, i) >= 99.95) {
    i++;
  }
  assert(i < sizeof prefix - 1);
  snprintf(dest, n, "%-.1f %.1s%s", b / pow(KSCALE, i), prefix + i, suffix);
  return dest;
}

#define PRT_BYTES(ull) \
    (PrintMetric((char [ULLONG_STRING_SIZE]){0}, ULLONG_STRING_SIZE, (ull), "b"))
//               ^----------------------------^ Compound literal
```

Usage
Notice multiple usages in a `printf()`.

```
#define GSCALE (1ull * KSCALE * KSCALE * KSCALE)
void fooo() {
  puts("Name          Available         Required");
  puts("------------- ----------------- ---------------");
  // Notice 2 calls to PRT_BYTES()
  printf("%-*s %-*s %-s\n", 13, "Something", 17, PRT_BYTES(10.1*GSCALE), PRT_BYTES(2.3*GSCALE));
  printf("%-*s %-*s %-s\n", 13, "Something", 17, PRT_BYTES(99949), PRT_BYTES(99950));
  printf("%-*s %-*s %-s\n", 13, "Something", 17, PRT_BYTES(0), PRT_BYTES(ULLONG_MAX));
}

int main() {
  fooo();
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Name          Available         Required
------------- ----------------- ---------------
Something     10.1 Gb           2.3 Gb
Something     99.9 kb           0.1 Mb
Something     0.0 b             18.4 Eb
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way would be to use the `"Gb(yte)"` indicators not within the same format string and implement them in the headings:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    printf("Name            Available (Gbyte)   Required (Gbyte)\n");
    printf("---------       ----------          ---------\n");
    printf("Something       %-12.1f        %.1f ", 125.0, 1444.6);
}
```

Output:

```
Name            Available (Gbyte)   Required (Gbyte)
---------       ----------          ---------
Something       125.0               1444.6
```