# Best way to grab 6 most significant bits from an unsigned int using operators in C?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I have managed to get rid of the first couple of bits but how would I only keep only the 6 most significant bits in C? I have tried `((num << 6) & 1)` with no luck

Comment: Try working out some examples on paper.  Do you want those bits as the top 6 bits of the result, or the bottom 6 bits?

Comment: @NateEldredge I want them as the top 6 bits (the 6 most significant bits)

Comment: Okay, then hint: you only need to `&` with an appropriate constant.

Comment: @NateEldredge so I don't even need to shift 6 bits to the left? I just need the & operator?

Comment: The bits you want are already in exactly the right place, so why would you shift them?  You just need to clear all the remaining bits to 0.

Comment: @NateEldredge I see, so would I just use the & operator with a 1 for the first 6 bits?

Comment: So you didn't work out the examples on paper, right? Just go do that. It will help you understand.

Comment: @0___________: Test that and see what you get.

Comment: @EricPostpischil obvious mistake (minus one is needed) as in my answer

Answer (score 3):

To get the most significant six bits of an integer and not the rest, bitwise AND it with a mask with the high six bits set and the rest clear.

Because `unsigned int` is a pure binary type, its maximum value, `UINT_MAX`, has all its bits set. Then `UINT_MAX >> 6` shifts those to the right, producing a result with the high six bits clear and the rest set. Performing a bitwise NOT, `~ (UINT_MAX >> 6)`, produces a result with the high six bits set and the rest clear.

Then  `num & ~ (UINT_MAX >> 6)` produces the high six bits of `num` with the remaining bits clear.

`UINT_MAX` is declared in `<limits.h>`. Due to C’s wrapping arithmetic for unsigned types, you can also get the maximum value of an `unsigned int` by using `-1u`, so `num & ~ (-1u >> 6)` will also work.

Answer (score 0):

Universal method not depending on the width of the integer

```
#define  C6B(num) ((num) & ~((1ull << (sizeof(num) * CHAR_BIT - 6)) - 1))
```

Comment: `~(x-1)` is `-x`, so `~((1ull << (sizeof(num) * CHAR_BIT - 6)) - 1))` is more simply `-1ull << sizeof (num) * CHAR_BIT - 6`. However, this is not universal since `unsigned long long` is not necessarily the widest type. `-1ull` could be replaced by `(uintmax_t) -1` or `-UINTMAX_C(1)` or `0*(num)-1u` or `(0?(num):-1u)`.

Answer (score 0):

OP wanted the 6 MSbits left in their [original place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69248132/best-way-to-grab-6-most-significant-bits-from-an-unsigned-int-using-operators-in?rq=1#comment122394085_69248132).  Other answers address that.

---

If we want these shifted into the least significant place, a common solution would look like the following.  This assumes that an `unsigned` has 32 bits. Although common, this is not specified by C.

```
num >> (32 - 6)
```

Alternatively we could use the below.  This assumes there are no padding bits, which is very common for `unsigned`.

```
#include <limits.h>
num >> (sizeof num * CHAR_BIT - 6)
```

Alternatively we could make no assumptions and determine bit width from `UINT_MAX` and [value bits of an integer type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4589384/2410359):

```
// Bits in a MAX integer type
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/4589384/2410359
#define IMAX_BITS(m) ((m)/((m)%255+1) / 255%255*8 + 7-86/((m)%255+12))

#include <limits.h>
#define UINT_VALUE_BITS IMAX_BITS(UINT_MAX)

num >> (UINT_VALUE_BITS - 6)
```