# Left rotate number by N bits

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

Suppose I have this number eg: **11** which in **base 2** is represented as : **1011** . I want to **left rotate by N** bits this number. So if **N = 5** (0101)  , then **1011 **left rotated by** 5**  should be **0111** =  7 .
Also ,numbers should always be represented on 4 bits.

I tried this approach but can't figure out  what the SIZE should be. If I set SIZE to 8 its output will be 353 which is not what I intended.

```
unsigned int op_lrotate(unsigned int nr1 , unsigned int nr2){
    return (nr1 << nr2)|(nr1 >> (SIZE - nr2));

}
int main(){
  unsigned int nr1=11;
  unsigned int nr2=5;
  unsigned int result = op_lrotate(nr1,nr2);
  printf("%u",result);
}
```

Comment: What happens if you use SIZE = 4?

Comment: it prints 352 for some reason

Comment: Print the bits, you'll see what's going on

Comment: What happens if you also truncate the result to 4 bits (`& 0x0F`)?

Comment: for SIZE 8 it outputs 1 , for SIZE 4 it it outputs 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work as you aren't accounting for the size of the variable correctly (where if it happened to somehow be a `uint4_t` (if such a type existed) the excess bits would have been shifted out).
Since you're rotating the value logically sized SIZE, you need to base your shifts on `nr2 % SIZE` and mask off the result accordingly.

For standard sized types, I'd suggest you look at [this answer for rotate best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/776523/20270).

In the specific case, see the example below, but note that SIZE must be <= the number of bits in the shifted type or undefined behavior will occur (hence the `assert`).

```
#include <limits.h>

#define SIZE (4)

unsigned int op_lrotate(unsigned int nr1, unsigned int nr2){
    unsigned int shift = nr2 % SIZE;
    unsigned int result;
    assert(SIZE <= (CHAR_BIT * sizeof(nr1)));
    if (!shift)
    {
        return nr1;
    }
    result = (nr1 << shift) | (nr1 >> (SIZE - shift));
    result &= (~0U >> (CHAR_BIT * sizeof(nr1) - SIZE));
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Nicely done. Run time `assert(SIZE <= (CHAR_BIT * sizeof(nr1)));` makes better sense as a compile time `_Static_assert`.

Comment: Only for the pedantic:  `CHAR_BIT * sizeof(nr1)` is the bit width of an `unsigned`.  What is needed is the bit width of the value bits.  Of course, with `unsigned` that is the same (no padding) in all but some [evil compiler](https://www.awelm.com/posts/evil-compiler/)?  To discern the value bit width, code could use [`IMAX_BITS(UINT_MAX)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4589384/2410359).