# Finding number of bits in an integer type

Tags: c

I have written a program to find number of bits on a given machine.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int int_size(void);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("%d\n", int_size());
    
 
    return 0;
}

int int_size(void)
{
    int count = 1;
    int value = 1;

    while (1)
    {   
        value <<= 1;
        if (value > 0)
        {
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }

    }

    return count + 1;
}
```

Now idea behind this is as follows. On most of the systems, left most bit is 1 for negative numbers. So, I start with 1. If the system used 8 bits for storing an integer, then 1 would be represented as 0000 0001. I then go on left shifting this number and then check whether its positive. Now, when number becomes, 1000 0000, left most bit is 1 and this would be taken as a negative number on most systems. So, while loop is exited and I get the count for the bits. I have tried this program on 7 online C compilers and all return value 32. So an integer has 32 bits on these systems. Now, I still don't know if my code is portable enough. Are there any machines that do not have left most bit as 1 for negative numbers ? I have come across three methods to store negative number. two's complement, one's complement and sign + magnitude. All three have left most bit 1 for negative numbers. So, this method should work on all systems.

Comment: Signed integer overflow causes *undefined behavior*. `CHAR_BITS * sizeof(int)` may be better.

Comment: "I still don't know if my code is portable enough". No it's not.

Comment: @Mike, I am not causing integer overflow here. When the leftmost bit is 1, loop is exited.

Comment: As @MikeCAT said, why even bother if you have sizeof which gives you this information

Comment: See, the compiler for a given architecture *knows* the size of the data types on this architecture, so there is no point to write a program to "determine" them in the run-time. Just ask the compiler as, for example @MikeCAT have suggested, or by examining the provided `INT_MAX/INT_MIN` values.

Comment: @user9026: Shifting a 1 into the sign bit of an `int` is integer overflow. The C standard defines left-shifting as a multiplication by a power of 2, and the mathematical result of a one-bit shift of 2^30 would be 2^31, but a 32-bit `int` cannot represent that value, so it overflows what an `int` can represent.

Comment: @KubaJ: `sizeof` includes padding bits, so it is not a fully portable way to determine the width of an integer type.

Comment: @KubaJ, I know that solution. I was trying to just do some basic bit manipulation to see how solution would look like.

Comment: You can determine the width using shifting by using `unsigned` instead of `int`. For `unsigned`, the shifting behavior is fully defined.

Comment: Related: [Is there any way to compute the width of an integer type at compile-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957252/is-there-any-way-to-compute-the-width-of-an-integer-type-at-compile-time)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now, I still don't know if my code is portable enough.

Your code has undefined behavior so the answer is: No

From C (draft) standard N1570:

> The result of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated bits are filled with
> zeros. If E1 has an unsigned type, the value of the result is E1 × 2<sup>E2</sup>, reduced modulo
> one more than the maximum value representable in the result type. **If E1 has a signed
> type and nonnegative value**, and E1 × 2<sup>E2</sup> is representable in the result type, then that is
> the resulting value; **otherwise, the behavior is undefined**.

When your `value` is at 2<sup>30</sup> and you do one more left shift, the result is 2<sup>31</sup> which isn't representable in an `int`. Therefore you end in the **"otherwise, the behavior is undefined"** part.

If you don't want to use `sizeof` then you can write a program using **unsigned** types and test for zero for detecting the overflow. You actually already do that so all you need is `unsigned int value = 1;` and you are safe.

That will work because the standard says:

> For each of the signed integer types, there is a corresponding (but different) unsigned
> integer type (designated with the keyword unsigned) that uses the same amount of
> storage (including sign information) ...

Comment: Great! Makes sense. Slava Ukraini !!

Answer (score 2):

> Now, I still don't know if my code is portable enough.

The program does not conform strictly to the C language specification.  That's pretty much the definition of "non-portable" as far as the language spec is concerned.

> I have come across three methods to store negative number. two's complement, one's complement and sign + magnitude. All three have left most bit 1 for negative numbers.

These are the three alternatives that C provides for, prior to C23.  All conforming implementations will use one of these.

> So, this method should work on all systems.

Not at all.  Shifts are operations on integer *values*, not on their *representations*.  You cannot conclude from the fact that there is a sign bit in each representation that you can ever produce a negative value by performing a left shift on a positive one.  The result of left-shifting a positive value of signed integer type is *undefined* if the type cannot represent the arithmetic result.

Generally speaking, you should use unsigned integer types when working with shifts and bitwise operations.  In particular, left-shifting a non-zero *unsigned* integer value until it becomes zero can give you information about the number of value bits in the type.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is portable as shift operations on unsigned numbers are well defined and the assignment of signed numbers with unsigned numbers is well defined too:

```
int int_size(void)
{
    int count = 0;
    int value = ~0;

    while ((value = ((unsigned)value) >> 1))
    {   
        count++;
    }

    return count + 1;
}
```