Avoiding unsigned overflow during multiplications using a max limit - how to define the limit value?
I need to compute recursively an integer number represented by an unsigned int down a tree.
Each node is associated with an integer value calculated recursively by multiplying the numbers of its children. The leaves have each a non-calculated static number, each being > 0.
The problem is frequent overflows. Actually, I am not interested when the result is a high number. I am OK if the result I obtain just tell me the value is > SOME_BIG_VALUE for instance (I don't need the real value in such a case).
My idea is to use the value 0 (otherwise never used) as a convention for any "high number" and
//when multiplying a and b each being <= SOME_BIG_VALUE, there is no overflow
unsigned c = a*b; 
// add a check 
if (c > SOME_BIG_VALUE)
   c = 0;

What is the cleanest way to define SOME_BIG_VALUE with its highest possible value for avoiding overflow ?
I consider using the definition :
#DEFINE SOME_BIG_VALUE unsigned(sqrt(UINT_MAX));

But it looks kind of dirty, isn't it ?
I know that in most case, unsigned are represented by 32 or 64 bits but I am not sure it is guaranteed. If it is I can check in which configuration we are and create define SOME_BIG_VALUE respectively to 2^16-1 ou 2^32-1.

What do you mean by "dirty"?

^^^ what he asked.  It looks as clean as a silicon chip factory to me.

If you want a test for unsigned multiplication overflow, this is covered in Mutliplication overflow test. But you seem to be asking for some sort of incomplete substitute test, like you are willing to declare an “overflow” of what your code can handle before an actual overflow of what the unsigned arithmetic can provide. In this case, you need to clarify what criteria this alternative needs to satisfy.

If you wish to satisfy the constraint that the condition will be detected before some a and b do cause a*b to overflow unsigned, then the value you proposed, (unsigned) sqrt(UINT_MAX), is the largest threshold that can be applied (in the absence of any information about asymmetry between a and b), and so that is what you should use. If you are averse to using sqrt but are willing to assume that unsigned uses an even number of bits and has no padding, then UINT_MAX >> sizeof (unsigned)*CHAR_BIT/2 would work.

@pmg The test could fail if there are padding bits. If the C23 UINT_WIDTH and similar constants are available, those would be more reliable.

@EricPostpischil I was not very confident about the rounding and conversion as sqrt(UINT_MAX) is not an integer.

You could probably do something like do c = a * b; if (c / a != b) c = 0;, but it does add some "expensive" computation.

@Arnaud to avoid many rounding and conversion issues of (unsigned) (sqrt(UINT_MAX), use (unsigned) sqrt((UINT_MAX/2 + 1)*2.0) - 1).  No need to - 1 when the # of unsigned value bits is odd.

@EugeneSh. That also needs a test to avoid divide by zero, e.g. c = a * b; if (a && c / a != b) c = 0;.

Avoiding unsigned overflow a * b
Many approaches involve finding the square root of UINT_MAX or UINT_MAX + 1.
OP's sqrt test
This is certainly reasonable when the ((unsigned) sqrt(UINT_MAX)) is somehow coded to only evaluate once.
// Somewhat convoluted.
#define SOME_BIG_VALUE ((unsigned) sqrt(UINT_MAX))
static unsigned big_value = 0;
if (big_value == 0) {
  big_value = SOME_BIG_VALUE;
}
if (a > big_value || b > big_value) {
  // Potential overflow
}

A more pedantic approach could use:
#define SOME_BIG_VALUE ((unsigned) sqrt((UINT_MAX/2 + 1)*2.0) - 1) so the sqrt() is more likely exact as (UINT_MAX/2 + 1)*2.0 is a exact floating point power-of-2, the number of value bits in unsigned is very commonly even and even weak quality sqrt() get the root of even power-of-2 exactly right.
Bit width test
#define UINT_BITS (sizeof(unsigned)*CHAR_BITS)
#define SOME_BIG_VALUE ((1u << (UINT_BITS/2)) - 1)
if (a > SOME_BIG_VALUE || b > SOME_BIG_VALUE) {
  // Potential overflow
}

There are ways to handle an odd sizeof(unsigned)*CHAR_BITS or unsigned with padding (see below), yet the above works for common implementations.
Bit width UINT_MAX (even if unsigned has padding):
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/4589384/2410359  
/* Number of value bits in inttype_MAX, or in any (1<<k)-1 where 0 <= k < 2040 */  
#define IMAX_BITS(m) ((m)/((m)%255+1) / 255%255*8 + 7-86/((m)%255+12))
// Value bit width of UINT_MAX (handles padded types).
#define UINT_BITS IMAX_BITS(UINT_MAX)

C2X has UINT_WIDTH for the value-bit-width.
Run time check
if (a > 0 && b > UINT_MAX/a) {
  // a * b will overflow.
}

Wider math
#if ULLONG_MAX/UINT_MAX > UINT_MAX
  unsigned long long prod = a;
  prod *= b;
  if (prod > UINT_MAX) {
    // Overflow
 


Many thanks ! in the bit width solution, can I be sure that the precompilation pre-calculates SOME_BIG_VALUE once for all ? Or is it safer that I use a global variable (or a static class attribute in C++) ?

@Arnaud Yes, in the bit width solution, you can be sure that the pre-processor pre-calculates SOME_BIG_VALUE once for all.

If your compiler supports an overflow-checking builtin you should use that: __builtin_umul_overflow in GCC and Clang; check the documentation for other compilers.
unsigned c; 
if (__builtin_umul_overflow(a, b, &c)) {
    c = 0;
}

