# Convert long long to string in C?

Tags: c, string, casting, long-long

I'd like to convert a long long to a string in C.

```
long long x = 999;
```

I'd like to convert x to a string.  How could I go about doing that?

Thanks.

Comment: This answer gives a hint: [How to convert unsigned long to string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709713/how-to-convert-unsigned-long-to-string) and the [snprintf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf) man page the `long long` modifier: `ll`, *ell-ell*.

Comment: I'd like to store the string in a char* though?

Comment: That's exactly what @miku's comment explains how to do.

Comment: not really seeing it?

Comment: `sprintf(string, "%lld", x);`

Comment: @Tommy: You do not store the ascii representation of a `long long` **in** a `char *`, but you store it in the memory the `char *` is pointing to, as a `char *` is a pointer and contains nothing more than an address.

Answer (score 27):

```
long long x = 999;
char str[256];
sprintf(str, "%lld", x);
printf("%s\n", str);
```

Comment: It would be better, in general, to use `snprintf()`, though with the buffer size you specify and the data in use it is not crucial.