# Buffer size for converting unsigned long to string

Tags: c, string, pointers, malloc

In reference to question and the answer 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709713/how-to-convert-unsigned-long-to-string): Can I use this method so that the solution will be platform independent.

```
char *buff = (char*) malloc(sizeof(unsigned long)*8);
sprintf(buff, "%lu", unsigned_long_variable);
```

Here I am getting the value of buffer length as it will similar to unsigned long variable. Is this approach correct?

Comment: Please [see why not to cast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh : thanks for the tip but is it relevant to my doubt?! I seek to understand whether the above approach is platform independent or not.
And I want to understand if above method is correct or not. If incorrect, purely for understanding and learning!!

Comment: @SouravGhosh, is that a habit of yours posting this irrelevant and highly debatable advice everywhere?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: The thing is that there are arguments *for* casting the return value as well (see the comments under unwind's accepted answer), and posting that link under every single question that does cast `malloc()` is... well, what would you say if I'd post a link to my favourite coding style guide under every question that violates it?

Comment: @DevSolar Sir, maybe to the "regular"s like us, it's repetitive, but I consider this to be useful for people landing on particular question, say via Google search. Also, I never said that is a **must**. I've added link to the question itself (to avoid any possible bias) where the most upvoted answer favours the comment body. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to know how many characters are needed to represent the largest possible `unsigned long`. Correct?

To that end, you are trying to calculate the largest possible `unsigned long`:

```
sizeof(unsigned long)*8
```

That is faulty in several ways. For one, `sizeof` returns multiples of `char`, which need not be 8 bit. You should multiply with `CHAR_BIT` (from `<limits.h>`) instead. But even that is not necessary, because that very same header already does provide the largest possible value -- `UCHAR_MAX`.

Then you're making a mistake: Your calculation gives the size of the *integer* representation of `unsigned long` *in bits*. What you *want* is the size of the *string* representation in *characters*. This can be achieved with the `log10()` function (from `<math.h>`):

```
log10( UCHAR_MAX )
```

This will give you a `double` value that indicates the number of (decimal) digits in `UCHAR_MAX`. It will be a fraction, which you need to round *up* (1) (`ceil()` does this for you).

Thus:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
    char * buff = malloc( ceil( log10( UCHAR_MAX ) ) + 1 );
    //...
}
```

All in all, this is quite dodgy (I made *two* mistakes while writing this out, shame on me -- if you make mistakes when using this, shame on you). And it requires the use of the math library for something that `snprintf( NULL, ... )` can do for you more easily, as indicated by the Q&A you linked to.

---

(1): `log10( 9999 )` gives `3.9999565...` for the *four*-digit number.

Comment: But contrary to the explanations, your code does **not** round-up. Or, you forgot the trailing 0. Besides, C's `log` is the natural logarithm. We need `log10' .

Comment: Generic advice: Whenever a number appears in your source code that is not `1` or `0`, that's a code smell, a.k.a. [unnamed numerical constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Unnamed_numerical_constants). It is an indicator that you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @undur_gongor: Hurrr... another lesson of "test before post". I intended the `+ 1` to do the round-up, and promptly forgot the null byte terminator. :-D

Comment: I saw a lot of code containing things like `#define TWO 2` caused by mis-applying that advice.

Comment: @undur_gongor: I even saw `#define TWO 3` once. No kidding. But you can mis-apply *any* advice if you put your mind to it. And I said "code smell", which means you *might* be doing something wrong, not that you *are* doing something wrong. (You'd need `2` to check for even numbers, for example.)

Answer (score 3):

Don't even *try* to calculate the buffer size.

Start with `snprintf`, which will tell you safely how many characters are needed. Then you know how many bytes to allocate to print safely.

Since this is a few lines of code that you don't want to repeat again and again, write a function `malloc_printf` that does exactly what you want: In that function, call `snprintf` with a NULL destination, then `malloc` the buffer, `sprintf` into the `malloc` buffer, and return it. To make it faster and to often avoid two `snprintf` and `sprintf` calls, write into a buffer of 256 chars first which is often enough.

So your final code would be

```
char* buff = malloc_printf ("%lu", unsigned_long_variable);
```

Also does quick, safe and easy string concatenation using the  format `%s%s`, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. In fact I used it in my code too. But the other answers cleared my doubt. Thanks btw.

Answer (score 1):

[The C standard doesn't put an upper limit to the number of bits per char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600378/portable-code-bits-per-char).

If someone constructs a C compiler that uses for example 2000 bits per char the output can overflow the buffer.

Instead of `8` you should use `CHAR_BIT` from limits.h.

Also, note that you need (slighly less than) 1 char per 3 bits and you need 1 byte for the string terminator.

So, something like this:

```
#include <limit.h>

char *buff = malloc(1 + (sizeof(unsigned long) * CHAR_BIT + 2) / 3);
sprintf(buff, "%lu", unsigned_long_variable);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not the right way to calculate the buffer size.

E.g. for 4 byte unsigned longs you have values up to 2^32-1
which means 10 decimal digits. So your buffer needs 11 chars.

You are allocating 4 * 8 = 32.

The correct formula is

```
ceil(log10(2^(sizeof(unsigned long) * CHAR_BIT) - 1)) + 1
```

(`log10` denotes the decimal logarithm here)

A good (safe) estimation is:

```
(sizeof(unsigned long) * CHAR_BIT + 2) / 3 + 1
```

because log10(2) is less than 0.33.

Comment: use `CHAR_BIT` to remove the assumption about char size

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

```
#define INTEGER_STRING_SIZE(t) (sizeof (t) * CHAR_BIT / 3 + 3)

unsigned long x;
char buf[INTEGER_STRING_SIZE(x)];
int len = snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%lu", x);
if (len < 0 || len >= sizeof buf) Handle_UnexpectedOutput();
```

---

OP's use of `sizeof(unsigned long)*8` is weak.  On systems where `CHAR_BIT` (the # of bits per `char`) is large (it must be at least 8), `sizeof(unsigned long)` could be 1. `1*8` `char` is certainly too small for `4294967295` (the minimum value for `ULONG_MAX`).

Concerning: `sprintf()/snprintf()` Given *locale* issues, in theory, code may print additional characters like `4,294,967,295` and so exceed the anticipated buffer.  Unless very tight memory constraints occur, recommend a 2x anticipated sized buffer.

```
char buf[ULONG_STRING_SIZE * 2];  // 2x
int len = snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%lu", x);
```

The expected maximum string width of printing some unsigned integer is `ceil(log10(unsigned_MAX)) + 1`.  In the case of of `unsigned long`, the value of `ULONG_MAX` certainly does not exceed `pow(2,sizeof (unsigned long) * CHAR_BIT) - 1` so code could use:

```
#define LOG10_2 0.30102999566398119521373889472449
#define ULONG_STRING_SIZE (sizeof (unsigned long) * CHAR_BIT * LOG10_2 + 2)
// For greater portability, should use integer math.
#define ULONG_STRING_SIZE (sizeof (unsigned long) * CHAR_BIT / 3 + 2)
// or more precisely
#define ULONG_STRING_SIZE (sizeof (unsigned long) * CHAR_BIT * 28/93 + 2)
```

The short answer used `+3` in case a *signed*` integer was specified.