# Freeing dynamically allocated matrix

Tags: c, malloc

I have this code for allocating a float matrix on runtime:

```
float **create_matrix(int w, int h) {
    // alocates the matrix rows first
    float **matrix = (float**)malloc(h * sizeof(float*));

    // now allocates and populates each line
    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
        matrix[i] = (float*) malloc(w * sizeof(float));

    // sample matrix filling
    for (int j = 0; j < w; j++)
        matrix[i][j] = (i + 1) * (j + 1);
    }

    return matrix;
}
```

It seems to be working fine, since it doesn't crash and when I display the matrix I have the very same values that I initialized it. Although when I try to free the matrix, iff the number of rows is lesser than the number of columns, I receive the following error message:

> a.out(14284,0x7fff73cc9300) malloc: *** error for object 0x9000000000000000: pointer being freed was not allocated
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug. Abort trap: 6"

My freeing routine follows:

```
void free_matrix(float **matrix, int h) {
    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
        free(matrix[i]);
    free(matrix);
}
```

Comment: are you sure you're passing the same `h` value for both?

Comment: FYI: [don't cast malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: Shame, shame, shame. Spent a lot of time reading the code and looking for the bug that I overlooked that. Should I delete the question?
And why not, @Barmar?

Comment: First see if it solved your problem.

Comment: @ameyCU. Already tried it. Not it is working.

Comment: @lfelix Not it is working? what do you mean by that ?

Comment: @Barmar Sir, beware, [people may accuse you for posting "debatable and irrelevant" comment.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31536174/buffer-size-for-converting-unsigned-long-to-string#comment51033100_31536174) :-)

Comment: @SouravGhosh I'll take my chances :)

Comment: @ameyCU, typo. noW it is working.

Comment: OT: All `int`s should better be `size_t`s.

Answer (score -3):

Try this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float **create_matrix(int h, int w)
{
    float **matrix = (float **)malloc(h*sizeof(float *));
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<h;i++){
       matrix[i] = (float *)malloc(w*sizeof(float));
    }
    for(i=0;i<h;i++){
        for(j=0;j<w;j++){
            matrix[i][j] = (i+1)*(j+1);
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}

int main()
{
    int h = 2, w = 3;
    float **matrix = create_matrix(h,w);
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<h;i++){
        for(j=0;j<w;j++){
            printf("%.2f ",matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You need to allocate memory before you start making operations.

Comment: @lfelix please check this

Comment: Actually the original code is working fine. As pointed out by @SouravGhosh I was using a wrong parameter for `h` on the free_matrix() call.